# XSLT copy-of select is not copying all the attributes in xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

I am using this xslt 1.0

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//row[@type='data']/column/item/content/div/select/option[@selected='selected'][. = 'Home']/../@*"/>
```

it is not copying all the attributes of 'select' element.

and my xml is

```
<row type="data">
  <column>
    <item>
      <content>
        <div id='win0divDERIVED_SS_PD_PHONE_TYPE$2'>
          <select name='DERIVED_SS_PD_PHONE_TYPE$2' id='DERIVED_SS_PD_PHONE_TYPE$2' tabindex='57' size='1' class='PSDROPDOWNLIST' style='width:221px; ' onchange="if (document.readyState == 'complete') addchg_win0(this);submitAction_win0(this.form,this.name);">
            <option value="BUSN">Business</option>
            <option value="CAMP">Campus</option>
            <option value="DORM">Dormitory</option>
            <option value="FAX">FAX</option>
            <option value="HOME" selected='selected'>Home</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </content>
    </item>
  </column>
</row>
```

Any idea? where i have made mistake? pls

i am using saxon processor and am expecting HTML output, that particular `select` element should be reproduced as it is in the input on the output. I dont know where i need to scrutinize? any help?

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples and information like XSLT processor used, output you want, the one you get, that allow us to easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Honnen: I have edited my post for your better understanding on my probelem. Please have a look at it.

Comment: You've told us what this code is _not_ doing, can you explain what it _is_ doing instead?  That `copy-of` should add the attributes from the `select` element onto whatever element you most recently output in your XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

Used following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//row[@type='data']/column/item/content/div/select/option[@selected='selected'][. = 'Home']/../@*"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and got the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root name="DERIVED_SS_PD_PHONE_TYPE$2" id="DERIVED_SS_PD_PHONE_TYPE$2" tabindex="57" size="1" class="PSDROPDOWNLIST" style="width:221px; " onchange="if (document.readyState == 'complete') addchg_win0(this);submitAction_win0(this.form,this.name);"/>
```

Comment: Were you looking for the same?

Comment: My xslt have bulk of code,there some of the portions are working and some of them is not working as coded as mentioned above. How to identify any clue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to reproduce that `select` element (and not just its attributes by themselves) the appropriate path to use with `copy-of` would be:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//row[@type='data']/column/item/content/div/select
                                         [option[@selected='selected'] = 'Home']"/>
```

In your question you say it's not copying "all of" the attributes. Does that mean it's copying *some of* the attributes but not others? What are you actually observing?